# Does anyone know how to change the page titles in react using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a website built using MVC6 and Razor syntax, a part of the site is built using react and TypeScript.

I need to update the page names for the tracking but I cant seem to find a way that will allow me to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Check React Helmet
https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

or React Document Meta
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-document-meta